# Is there a way for Banshee to rename a song file according to it's tags?

Tags: 11.04, banshee, files, mp3, rename

For example, I have a file called `HCYD.mp3` on my Music folder.

If I open it in Banshee I see the actual song name, artist, etc.

Is there a way to rename the file (actual file name!) to something like: `Frank Sinatra - My Way.mp3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit -> Preferences** and tick the **Update file and folder names** box.

[image]

Then flick to the Source Specific tab to set how you want the folders and files named.

[image]

Unfortunately, the files aren't renamed automatically. They only update when you manually change the tags.

The only way to achieve this today is to select all songs,
right click and choose 'edit track information' and then keep clicking Forward (or keep pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to go through all the songs without changing any of the values, then on the final song hitting 'Save', this causes the renaming process to be invoked.

For more finegrained control over renamed individual files then you could install [EasyTAG](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/easytag) [image: Install EasyTAG].

```
sudo apt-get install easytag
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to do exactly what I want it to do. However, it doesn't seem to change anything. Is this done in the background when it feels like it, or can I force it to start renaming?

Comment: @Sergio it only writes the metadata for files that you edit the metadata for. See [this wishlist bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=579944)